# Confused regarding CMI question

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math, examples-counterexamples

I think there might be an error in the official solution to the following question:

[CMI May 23, 2022 BSc entrance exam](https://www.cmi.ac.in/admissions/sample-qp/ugmath2022-23may.pdf), Question A2(7):

> You are asked to take three *distinct* points $1, \omega_1, \omega_2$ in the complex plane such that $|\omega_1|=|\omega_2|=1$. Consider the triangle $T$ formed by the the complex numbers $1, \omega_1, \omega_2$:
>
> > (7) If $\omega_1+\omega_2$ is real, the triangle $T$ must be isosceles.

The [official solution](https://www.cmi.ac.in/admissions/sample-qp/ugmath2022-23may-partA-solutions.pdf) tells that the statement is true.

But I think I might have a counterexample:

What if we choose $\omega_1=\omega$ and $\omega_2=-\omega$?

Doesn’t that satisfy the criteria without the triangle being isosceles?

Perhaps ‘nonzero real’ might have been a more appropriate choice in the question statement.

[image]

Comment: Yes, your example is good.

Comment: @K.Jiang do you think that the question might be wrong, then? Or rather, its solution is wrong?

Comment: @SohamSaha It's hard to say, because the "solution" is not really a solution, just an answer. My guess is that they overlooked the cases where you have $\omega_1 = -\omega_2$ and only considered the cases $\omega_1 = \bar{\omega}_2$.

Comment: @K.Jiang Yes, that was my guess too. Nonzero real might have been more appropriate in the question statement

Comment: @SohamSaha Right, if it is further required that $\omega_1 + \omega_2 \ne 0$, then they are forced to be conjugates.

Comment: It is obvious from your construction that you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes are true because
is w1 and w2 both have same modulus 1
and if sum of both is purely real
so
Im(w1)=-Im(w2)=m

And we know that

Re(w1)²+Im(w2)²=1
Re(w2)²+Im(w2)²=1 // Modulus

subtract both

Re(w1)²=Re(w2)²
Re(w1)=±Re(w2)=k

w1=k+im
w2=±k-im
w3=1

So if you draw these
you can see that
only w2=k-im is valid

So yes you are correct